# How do I show a splash screen in Android?

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I want to show a splash screen when my app loads up, this is my `Java` code:

```
ImageView splash = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);

splash.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}, 3000);
```

But I am getting the error **"cannot resolve symbol"** on the `postDelayed()` call. Also I get the **"unexpected token"** for

```
}, 3000);
```

Finally, this is my layout:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Logcat:

```
9:41:01 PM Throwable
       Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
       Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 239,4,main] 359404630
       Our dispatch thread:Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 0.4.2#AI-133.970939, eap:true,6,main] 1198871553
       SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 0.4.2#AI-133.970939, eap:true,6,main] 1198871553
```

9:41:13 PM Compilation completed successfully in 12 sec

The manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.conversation" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.conversation.splash"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
private static final int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;
private static final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class)); 
                finish();   
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);    
}
```

Here `activity_splash.xml` is your `splash` *Activity* layout and `YourActivity` is the *Activity* you're going to next.

Answer (score 0):

```
private ImageView splash;


splash = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
public void run() {
        splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}, 3000);
```

Try this.